# Error : Failed to load the native Tensorflow runtime

Tags: tensorflow

I got this error with tensorflow and i can't find a way to resolve it.
I got : 
Python 3.6.8
Tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 
Cuda 10.1
Cudnn 7.5.1

The error is as follows:

```
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "E:\projects\venv\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I've followed this installation guide : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
I've properly edit all paths like explained.

And i don't really understand how i can fix this error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TF 1.13 comes with cuda 10.0 pre-built binaries. Please download cuda 10.0 toolkit and update cuda, cudnn paths. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements
By default Nvidia hosts the latest cuda release (currently it has 10.1) which may not be present in latest stable TF binary. You can select cuda 10.0 from this link https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive.